# Refresh JTable when typed text is a row in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I have a `JTable` with 7 columns and 2 rows. Below my `JTable` I have a `JTextField`. When I type something in `JTextField`, I can easly get what I typed: `String lookFor = this.jTextField2.getText();`

But now, I would like to refresh my `JTable` after I type something in my `JTextField` but only when a row (or rows) contain(s) a text from `JTextField`. I tried this, with no result:

```
public Object[][] getTableData(JTable table) {
        DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
        Object[][] tableData = new Object[nRow][nCol];
        for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++) {
                tableData[i][j] = dtm.getValueAt(i, j);
            }
        }
        return tableData;
    }

private void jTextField2KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        DefaultTableModel newTableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
        String lookFor = this.jTextField2.getText();

        Object[][] td = getTableData(this.myTable);

        int rows = td.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            String brand = (String) td[0][0];
            String model = (String) td[0][1];
            String serialNumber = (String) td[0][2];
            String date = (String) td[0][3];
            String firstname = (String) td[0][4];
            String lastname = (String) td[0][5];
            String desc = (String) td[0][6];

            if (brand.contains(lookFor) || model.contains(lookFor) || serialNumber.contains(lookFor) || date.contains(lookFor)
                    || firstname.contains(lookFor) || lastname.contains(lookFor) || desc.contains(lookFor));
            newTableModel.addRow(new Object[]{brand, model, serialNumber, date, firstname, lastname, desc});

        }

        this.myTable.setModel(newTableModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to do table filtering.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a working example that will filter the rows displayed as you enter text in a text field.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, and what you forgot to do is set columns for the new model. You must either do

```
newTableModel.setColumnCount(7)
```

or

```
newTableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[] { ... });
```

Only when you do this, will you see what the new data looks like in the already shown table.